Not able to use array of elements in annotation for this case with JCommander library
I am trying to use JCommander library with groovy, I am using this test script based on code on the library documentation, here one of the important part
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.jcommander', module='jcommander', version='2.0')
)
import com.beust.jcommander.*

Flags flags = new Flags()

JCommander.newBuilder()
  .addObject(flags)
  .build()
  .parse(args);

println "OK"


@Parameters(parametersValidators = QuietAndVerboseAreMutualExclusive.class)
public class Flags {
    @Parameter(names = "--quiet", description = "Do not output anything")
    boolean quiet;

    @Parameter(names = "--verbose", description = "Output detailed information")
    boolean verbose;
}

public class QuietAndVerboseAreMutualExclusive implements IParametersValidator {

    @Override
    public void validate(Map<String, Object> parameters) throws ParameterException {
        // validation stuff
    }
}


the problem is on
@Parameters(parametersValidators = QuietAndVerboseAreMutualExclusive.class)

I get as error
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/tmp/2/test.groovy: 18: 'parametersValidators'is not part of the annotation Parameters in @com.beust.jcommander.Parameters
 @ line 18, column 1.
   @Parameters(parametersValidators = QuietAndVerboseAreMutualExclusive.class)
   ^

/tmp/2/test.groovy: 18: Unexpected type java.lang.Object in @com.beust.jcommander.Parameters
 @ line 18, column 36.
   @Parameters(parametersValidators = QuietAndVerboseAreMutualExclusive.class)
                                      ^

2 errors

this is the javadoc of the Parameters annotation @Parameters javadoc, it seems I am using it correctly.
I tried several other ways like
@Parameters(parametersValidators = [QuietAndVerboseAreMutualExclusive.class])

@Parameters(parametersValidators = [QuietAndVerboseAreMutualExclusive.class] as Class[])

